Formula to look at one sheet and find the match on another sheet
I have a Google Sheet that I want to update another Google sheet when it finds a match. In the sheet, I have a tab named 'Master Sheet', a data entry sheet with multiple entries with the same data as the box moves through the process. I have another tab called 'Box List' that contains all the boxes that need to be worked. I am looking for a formula that when an entry is made on 'Master Sheet' it finds the matching 'Transfer #' and corresponding 'Box #' on the 'Box List' tab and updates the 'Completed' column with true only when it is true.
Sample Google Sheet

Since you have duplicates of Transfer # + Box # in the Master sheet; whats your expectation on picking up the completed status for such special scenarios?!

@rockinfreakshow I would like the Box List tab to be updated when the formula finds a match in the Master Sheet of the Transfer # and Box #. Mark it on the Box List tab as True in the completed column. I'm trying to "automate" this as much as possible that way everything auto-updates when entries are put in on the Master Sheet. Hope that makes sense.

that doesnt answer the posed question regarding duplicates. for example Transfer(052-94-0142)+Box(32) has 2 rows of data in master sheet. One row is marked true for completed status while the other row is marked false! Whats the deciding factor here?! Should we explicitly look for TRUE status?

@rockinfreakshow Theoretically, there shouldn't be any duplicates because each box should only be marked TRUE for the Completed status once and yes, the formula should explicitly look for TRUE status in that column and then find the matching Transfer and Box number on the Box List tab. Sorry for not answering your question about duplicates earlier.
